# save base64 image python

Tags: python, image, radix

I am trying to save an image with python that is Base64 encoded. Here the string is to large to post but here is the image

[image]

And when received by python the last 2 characters are `==` although the string is not formatted so I do this

```
import base64
data = "data:image/png;base64," + photo_base64.replace(" ", "+")
```

And then I do this

```
imgdata = base64.b64decode(data)
    filename = 'some_image.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
```

But this causes this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/save_info.py", line 83, in &lt;module&gt;
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding
```

I also printed out the length of the string once the `data:image/png;base64,` has been added and the `spaces` replace with `+` and it has a length of `34354`, I have tried a bunch of different images but all of them when I try to open the saved file say that the file is damaged.

What is happening and why is the file corrupt?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is some base64 that also failed

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADBQTFRFA6b1q Ci5/f2lt/9yu3 Y8v2cMpb1/DSJbz5i9R2NLwfLrWbw m T8I8////////SvMAbAAAABB0Uk5T////////////////////AOAjXRkAAACYSURBVHjaLI8JDgMgCAQ5BVG3//9t0XYTE2Y5BPq0IGpwtxtTP4G5IFNMnmEKuCopPKUN8VTNpEylNgmCxjZa2c1kafpHSvMkX6sWe7PTkwRX1dY7gdyMRHZdZ98CF6NZT2ecMVaL9tmzTtMYcwbP y3XeTgZkF5s1OSHwRzo1fkILgWC5R0X4BHYu7t/136wO71DbvwVYADUkQegpokSjwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

This is what I receive in my python script from the POST Request

Note I have not replace the spaces with +'s

Comment: can you add a small sample of what you received as base64 encoded? Use very small image (like favicon). AFAIK there is no space in base64 encoded image.

Comment: So why are you using `"data:image/png;base64," + photo_base64.replace(" ", "+")` and not just`imgdata = base64.b64decode(photo_base64)`?

Comment: @KevinGuan  because when I send the send to the python script the + get replace by spaces so I am just putting the +'s back and Ali about to post some data

Comment: @AliNikneshan posted some data

Comment: @KevinGuan I tried that, and got same error, I didn't replace spaces or add `data:image/png;base64,`

Comment: What did you expect? Base64 strings can not contain spaces and your sample string contains it. If I replace it with '+'  I recieve some PNG `In [13]: s.replace(' ', '+').decode('base64')
Out[13]: '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n ...`

Comment: Okay, so Alik is right. Don't add `data:image/png;base64,`, just replace space with `'+'`.

Answer (score 18):

There is no need to add `data:image/png;base64,` before, I tried using the code below, it works fine.

```
import base64
data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADBQTFRFA6b1q Ci5/f2lt/9yu3 Y8v2cMpb1/DSJbz5i9R2NLwfLrWbw m T8I8////////SvMAbAAAABB0Uk5T////////////////////AOAjXRkAAACYSURBVHjaLI8JDgMgCAQ5BVG3//9t0XYTE2Y5BPq0IGpwtxtTP4G5IFNMnmEKuCopPKUN8VTNpEylNgmCxjZa2c1kafpHSvMkX6sWe7PTkwRX1dY7gdyMRHZdZ98CF6NZT2ecMVaL9tmzTtMYcwbP y3XeTgZkF5s1OSHwRzo1fkILgWC5R0X4BHYu7t/136wO71DbvwVYADUkQegpokSjwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='.replace(' ', '+')
imgdata = base64.b64decode(data)
filename = 'some_image.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(imgdata)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you append **data:image/png;base64,** to data, then you get error. If You have this, you must replace it.

```
new_data = initial_data.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '')
```